# Run Compass with --sourcemap flag

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Does Compass support the --sourcemap option in Sass yet? I would like to run Sass through Compass. I have

```
sass_options = {:sourcemap => true}
```

in my config.rb, but when I run `compass watch` in my project folder no sourcemap files are generated. On the other hand, when I run

```
sass --compass --sourcemap --watch scss:css
```

The source file is generated, but the config.rb is ignored.

(For anybody wondering what a sourcemap is, it's a file that allows Developer Tools inspector to point to the origin of a style in a Sass scss file when you inspect an element.)

Comment: https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1108

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Source maps are included starting with Sass 3.3 or later, which is only compatible with Compass 1.0.

https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1108

Adding the following to your config.rb will only add the sourcemap information directly to your compiled CSS:

```
sass_options = { :debug_info => true }
```

Output:

```
@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/\/home\/chris\/compass\/sass\/test\.scss}line{font-family:\0000314}}
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

To get your sourcemap file(s), you need to add this option to your config.rb:

```
sourcemap = true
```

Console output:

> ```
> $ compass watch
>  modified config.rb
>     clean css
>    delete css/test.css
> >>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
>     write css/test.css
>     write css/test.css.map
> ```

Answer (score 13):

The solution provided by @cimmanon didn't work for me. What worked for me was the following (credits to Serge-Z in https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1108):

```
sudo gem install compass-sourcemaps --pre
```

Then you just do `compass watch` as usual with `sass_options = {:sourcemap => true}` in your config.rb.

In case you are on OS X El Capitan and have problems installing due to rootless mode (credits to Thomzzzzz in https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/2018):

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass-sourcemaps --pre
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it works with

```
sourcemap = true
```

in config.rb (solution taken from https://chillco.com/blog/setting-sass-and-compass-source-maps)

I'm using compass via Koala (http://koala-app.com/)